# animate Kivy Bezier curve with custom width ? (a bit silly question)

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, bezier

update: After discussing with others, I decided that it is a bit silly question. I wanted to animate Bezier curve with changed width, but it has no width property. with Line Bezier, I can change width, but then can't animate.

---

I can't change `witdh` of `Bezier` curve like `Line`. 
here is the code:

```python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__()
        with self.canvas:
            self.L=Bezier(points=[200,450,500,300,600,150],width=12)
            self.k=Line  (bezier=[100,350,400,200,500,50 ],width=12)

class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

and outupt:
[image: MyApp]

### the problem is,

the upper curve isn't `width=12`.

I think that's because Kivy's Bezier Class has no attribute `width` cuz when  I do it on `kv` lang, it gives me `AttributeError: 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Bezier' object has no attribute 'width'`. Well, why not using `Line` with `bezier` ? I want to use `Animation` on it and when I try to on `Line` with `bezier`, I get `AttributeError: attribute 'bezier' of 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Line' objects is not readable`.

### so the question,

how can I change `width` of `Bezier`. if it is not possible, is there any way like finding the y of cruve (or ys) for given x so I can put `Ellipse` on these points and resize them to simulate width ?

thanks and pardon my english `♥`

Comment: It sounds like your question isn't what you wrote. What you _want_, in your own words, is to animate (although you don't show the code you tried, which you should), so "the quesiton" should be: how to achieve that animation. Not how to give a Bezier path a width, which doesn't make sense: Bezier paths have no width, it models a (closed) path and can be filled in, it does not model a line that can be painted. Which is why it's `Bezier`, not `Line`.

Comment: > it models a (closed) path and can be filled in, it does not model a line that can be painted. oh yea really that's logical and probably that's why. and about my question improperness, I wanted to know changing `Bezier` width, not a _Bezier path_ width. then I will animate that `Bezier`, cuz I can't do it on `Line` _Bezier path_.

Comment: I have an idea, which animates the `Bezier` curve, then bind a `foo` to `Bezier` `points`. in `foo`, I will draw a new `Line` Bezier with `Bezier`'s points. haven't tried, but doesn't sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Also, I assume you've asked about this on the [Kivy users group](https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users)? Probably a good idea to put the link for that in your post, too.

Comment: I haven't thought about kivy users group. asking smthng bout specific module is better in specific platform. I just saw a ton of pandas question and thought that asking in overflow is kinda _default_ thing :d

Comment: stackoverflow is your "last resort", you post here _after_ [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask), which includes checking the official places first (or at least, in parallel =)

Comment: I searched. in docs, even in others' stackoverflow questions. I couldn't find anything. so I asked it to here. if someone would answer it, it would be great, if not, no problem. after talking with you and others , now I can see it doesn't really worth to ask. but too late, i did. anyways, thank to everyone who give it a time. i will put a note on top about that.

Comment: I'm not blaming you for asking, because if you think you searched everywhere, then that's what you think you did. However, I _am_ helping you understand that you didn't actually search everywhere: the first place to look is always the official documentation, and the official places for support (is it a github project? check the issue tracker. Does it have a mailing list? Does it have a user forum? Do they use Slack? Does it specifically tell you to post questions to SO, like some do?). This allows you to, in the future, better search for solutions.

Comment: As for this post: if there's a good answer then there's nothing wrong with having a post here _as well_. as long as you mention that you searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer so you're asking about it here as well as the official places to ask in the hopes of getting an answer. That's perfectly fine, and if you get an answer elsewhere you can post that answer here so that future visitors can find your post with its answer here, as well as wherever you got the answer. And vice versa: if you get an answer here, now you can self-answer the question elsewhere for those folks, too.

Comment: Finally, seriously: [follow the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). If you genuinely believe your question has no merit, delete it. If you think it _does_ have merit, don't update it to say it doesn't have merit, post your own answer that explains why the question doesn't actually apply. And definitely don't slap on a full paragraph of text with h2 formatting. Again: this is not a general help forum, by sticking to the posting guidelines we all ensure that SO stays a useful resource for future visitors like you or me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line can use `bezier:`, example:

```
Line:
    bezier:[n1,n2,n3,n4]
    width:3
```

This is a `Line`, not a `Bezier`, but you get the same result...

One example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

posicao=[]
class Draw(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Draw, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        posicao.append(touch.pos)
        
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        posicao.clear()
        
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        Line = Builder.load_string(
"""
FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:11,.1,1,1
        Line:
            points: {pos}
            width:14
""".format(pos=(touch.pos, posicao[0])))
        self.add_widget(Line)
        posicao.clear()
        posicao.append(touch.pos)
        
class Code(App):
    def build(self):
        return Draw()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Code().run()
```

Or:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import *

posi = []

Builder.load_string(
"""
<Draw>:
    
""")
class Draw(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Draw, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        posi.clear()
        posi.append(touch.pos)
        
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        posi.clear()
        
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Line(points=[posi[0], touch.pos],width=14)
        posi.clear()
        posi.append(touch.pos)
            
class Code(App):
    def build(self):
        return Draw()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Code().run()
```

Comment: Sure. But I can animate ```Line```. at least, its ```points```. But not why its ```bezier``` ? and I found that there is no such attribute in ```Line``` class. if you ask "why not using ```Bezier``` class?", cuz I can't change length of a ```Bezier``` line.

Comment: How do you want to animate the ```Line``` or ```Bezier```?  It all depends on what you want to do exactly ...

Comment: test in kv, i tested it.

Comment: I wanted to animate bezier curve with custom width. however, I no longer wanna dive in deeper Kivy. It is a fun tool on my backpack. If you have tried this and sure that this is working, I'm accapeting this question.

Answer (score 1):

The `Bezier` has no `width` property, but the `Line` does. So you can animate that `width`. An easy way to do that is by animating a `NumericProperty` that holds the width. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *

class MyLayout(Widget):
    line_width = NumericProperty(12)
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__()
        with self.canvas:
            self.L=Bezier(points=[200,450,500,300,600,150],width=self.line_width)
            self.k=Line  (bezier=[100,350,400,200,500,50 ],width=self.line_width)

    def on_line_width(self, instance, new_width):
        self.k.width = new_width

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.anim)
        return MyLayout()

    def anim(self, dt):
        a = Animation(line_width=3)
        a.start(self.root)

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

If you build the `Line` in `kv`, then you don't even need the `on_line_width()` method since kivy will do the binding for you.

Comment: No, please read carefully. I have no difficulty with `Line` and its properties and I know `Bezier` has no `width`:
>" I think that's because Kivy's Bezier Class has no attribute width. "what I want is to animate curve itself (that is not a problem), but with custom width.

Comment: I thought you were trying to animate the width. So, are you trying to animate the bezier points?

Comment: yea, points of Bezier which has a width. that's why I didn't want the bottom line in the example image.